# How to replace 1 and 0 with male and female in R?

Tags: r

I have a csv file contain a gender attribute with 1 = male and zero = female.
I want to replace this value from 1 to male and 0 to female after reading the dataset using R.
I tried this code but not working

```
df <- read.csv('heart.csv')
df[df$sex == 1] <- "male"
df[df$sex == 0] <- "female"
```

Comment: `c('female', 'male')[df$sex + 1]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your indexing wasn't working because you were trying to replace the entire data frame.  That is, `df[df$sex == 1]` was causing a problem because R doesn't know which elements you wanted to replace.   You could do the following:

```
df$sex[df$sex == 0] <- "female"
df$sex[df$sex == 1] <- "male"
```

Or, you could just make the variable into a factor.

```
df <- data.frame(
+   sex = c(1,0,0,1, NA)
+ )
df$sex <- factor(df$sex, 
                 levels=c(0,1), 
                 labels=c("female","male"))

df
#      sex
# 1   male
# 2 female
# 3 female
# 4   male
# 5   <NA>
```

Comment: you will have to reverse the order of the labels or levels, Note that female = 0, while male =1

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
 df <- data.frame(sex = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE))
 df$sex <- c('female', 'male')[df$sex + 1]
```

or what you were trying to do:

```
df[df$sex==1, 'sex'] <- "male"
df[df$sex==0, 'sex'] <- "female"
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try `mutate` from `dplyr` package and `ifelse`

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE))

> df
# A tibble: 10 x 1
       x
   <int>
 1     0
 2     1
 3     0
 4     1
 5     1
 6     1
 7     1
 8     0
 9     0
10     1

df <-df %>%
  mutate(y = ifelse(x == 0, "male", "female"))

> df
# A tibble: 10 x 2
       x y     
   <int> <chr> 
 1     0 male  
 2     1 female
 3     0 male  
 4     1 female
 5     1 female
 6     1 female
 7     1 female
 8     0 male  
 9     0 male  
10     1 female
```